# PHP cart in session show different products

Tags: php

I stored a temporary session value and product id in orderdetails table to store different product items and how it will shows that orderdetails values in cart page. Attachement will shown at below cases:

[image]

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("db.php");
include("header.php"); 
session_start();
$session_id = session_id();  
?>

<form action="#" class="form1"> 
<div class="cart-table table-responsive mb-40">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="pro-remove">Remove</th>
                <th class="pro-thumbnail">Image</th>
                <th class="pro-title">Product</th>
                <th class="pro-price">Price</th>
                <th class="pro-quantity">Quantity</th> 
                <th class="pro-subtotal"> Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <?php 
                $cartid = $_GET['proid'];  
                $sqlpd = mysql_query("select * from orderdetail where sessionid = '$session_id'")or die(mysql_error()); 
                while($getpd = mysql_fetch_array($sqlpd)){
                        $product_id = $getpd['product_id'];
                    ?> 
            <tr>
                <td class="pro-remove"><a href="javascript:void(0);"  name="cart_remove" id="cart_remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
                <td class="pro-thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="admin/<?php echo $getpd['medium_image'];?>" height="50" width="50">
                </td> 
                <td class="pro-title"><?php echo $getpd['product_id'];?></td>
                <td class="pro-price"><span><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo number_format($getpd['actual_price'],2);?>
        </span></td>

                <td class="pro-quantity">
                    <input type="number" class="cardqty-1" min="1" value="1" style="width:50px;">
                    <a href="javascript:void();" class="updatecart" data-id="1" data-prd_id="380" data-rowid="c2b5d53083a7597dd75ac36d9fd93581"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td class="pro-subtotal"><span><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo number_format($getpd['actual_price'],2);?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th >Sub Total</th>
                <th class="pro-subtotal text-center"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo number_format($getpd['actual_price'],2);?></th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th >GST(12%)</th>
                <th class="pro-subtotal text-center"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo number_format($getpd['actual_price'],2);?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th >Grand Total</th>
                <th class="pro-subtotal text-center"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><?php echo number_format($getpd['actual_price'],2);?></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

This code will like this...I will compare a session value from table and temp session_id. Query is working but I know the values will not correct but how can i set values from products table using product id(orderdetails-table).

[image]

[image]

Comment: change the query to "select * from `orderdetail` LEFT JOIN `products` ON orderdetail.product_id = products.product_id" and then print all fields like "<?php echo $getpd['item_name'];?>"

Comment: Thanks.....Thats working fine :)